# $compile doesn't insert scope variable into the HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test the rendering of an HTML with my scope variable inside my unit test.

HTML has 2 `<textarea>` which are as follows:

```
<textarea ng-model="a" ng-change="someFunction(a)" value={{a}}></textarea>
<textarea ng-model="b" ng-change="someFunction(b)" value={{b}}></textarea>
```

`a` and `b` are scope variables such that `a = someFunction(b)` and `b=someFunction(a)`.

Explanation: Typing in `a` calls the function `someFunction(a)` which changes the text in the textarea `b`. Vice versa for `b`.

The unit test I've written are as follows:

```
    var compile,
        scope,
        tc,
        template,
        controller,
        httpGuy;

    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $templateCache, $controller, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('ABCController', {'$scope': scope});
        compile = $compile;
        template = $templateCache.get('app/index.html');
    }));

it('test1', function() {
            scope.a = SOME_VALUE;
            scope.someFunction(scope.a);
            // at this point scope.b  changes to correct value
            var html_template = compile(template)(scope); // this should insert the scope variables in html?
            scope.$digest();
            console.log(angular.element(html_template.find('textarea')[1]));
        });
```

The test gives the output of `<textarea>` with `value=""` i.e. empty. Value should have been rendered because we introduced the scope variables in the HTML. 
Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: Explain "a and b are scope variables such that a = someFunction(b) and b=someFunction(b)."

Comment: added an explanation.

Comment: Show the code for the `ABCcontroller`.

Answer (score 1):

If the value of `$scope.b` in `ABCController` is not set, then the value will be `""`(empty string).

Try setting some value for it in controller, the same value will be available to `<textarea>` element in unit test.

[Here is the sample jsfiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/3c3exgs6/3/)

Trying to set some value to `scope.a` or `scope.b` inside a test case and then compiling wont insert the new assigned value to compiled dom, as the `template` will be having an `ng-controller='ABCController'`, which creates an new and fresh instance of the controller(with different scope). Hence the value set on `scope` object will not be of any effect.

If you want to set some values to scope and then want to compile the `template` with a particular scope object, then remove `ng-controller` from `template` and use below pattern

```
var compile,
    scope,
    controller;

beforeEach(function() {
    module("ABCControllerModule"); // Instantiate the 'ABCController' module
    inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
      scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      controller = _$controller_('ABCController', {'$scope': scope});
      compile = _$compile_;
    });
});

it('test1', function() {
    scope.a = SOME_VALUE;
    scope.someFunction = function(a) {
        ...
    };
    var html_template = compile(<template-with-out-ng-controller->)(scope);
    console.log(angular.element(html_template.find('textarea')[1]));
});
```

Comment: But I need to check other elements in the html file as well. My question is why isn't the injecting happening with the html file!?

Comment: To add to this, don't store primitive variables directly on scope. IE boolean,string,number.  Store them inside of another object.

Comment: @saru95 Updated the answer with sample jsfiddle which demonstrate why `value` is `""`. Do check once and let me know whether it answers your question or not ?